# bear trap memory

Tags: idioms

What does "**bear trap memory**" mean? Or **bear-trap memory**? Any why "**bear trap**"? I googled and saw a few examples. But none is very explanatory. An example of usage:

> ... I was caught by his *bear trap memory* of grammar again. ...

Comment: Could you please show the sentence where you found this phrase?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A bear trap is a trapping device for large animals. Once it has something trapped, it doesn't let go.

[image: Example bear trap]

Someone has a *bear trap memory* if, having learnt something, they never forget it.

Comment: Just when I was going to answer it. Anyway, +1

Comment: is it a recent term?

Answer (score 13):

I'm much more familiar with a similar phrase:

> She has a mind like a *steel* trap.

Which means that, in addition to having a strong memory (that grabs onto facts and never lets them go), also suggests that a person quickly understands and assimilates new concepts. See [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+mind+like+a+steel+trap) and [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mind+like+a+steel+trap,+have+a):

> **have a mind like a steel trap**: to be able to think very quickly, clearly and intelligently

from the Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.

Answer (score 7):

I think what the speaker means is that the person they are referring to has an excellent memory for grammar and never forgets. The speaker made a mistake in their grammar and the other person noticed it.

A bear trap is a mechanical device that is powerful enough for a bear to trap and hold a bear. Considering that bears are very large and strong animals, this phrase is supposed to show how good the person's memory is: once it holds something, it never lets go!

I don't know how common this phrase is. I don't hear it very often.

Comment: +1 for detail explanation. Indeed, not very many hits when I googled.

Answer (score -1):

Bear trap, steel trap - same thing. Means long-lasting and *precise* memory. You probably hear it more often than you remember? Meaning you probbly don't have one ;)